# getting the contenents of a GridPane javafx

Tags: javafx, textfield, gridpanel

I have a GridPane in every row there's a Hbox which contain labels and textfields. I want to get the text that the user writes in the textfields and also get the text written in the labels how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask a question, please include the relevant code for the issue you are asking for help on. Also, before asking here, make sure you have done some research on the issue, and can demonstrate that you have put effort into solving it yourself first. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author reegan
 */
public class GridPaneStackOverFlow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        gp.add(createNode("Stack"), 0, 0);
        gp.add(createNode("Over"),0,1);
        gp.add(createNode("Flow"), 0, 2);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(gp);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public HBox createNode(String label) {
        HBox box = new HBox(20);
        final Label l = new Label(label);
        TextField field = new TextField();
        field.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1) {
                System.out.println( l.getText()+ " : " +t);
            }
        });
        box.getChildren().addAll(l,field);
        return box;

    }

}
```